# Is $\exists x \forall y \exists z P(x,y,z)$ satisfiable?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have this formula:
$$\begin{align}
\exists x \forall y \exists z P(x,y,z) \\
\end{align}$$

How to check whether it is *satisfiable*? I know that I have to find a structure in which it is *true*.

Comment: Stupid question: What does "executable" mean?

Comment: @NikolajK practicable maybe or feasible

Comment: Practicable maybe or feasible? I still don't know what you mean, but if you set $P(x,y,z):=(1=1)$, then the formula holds. Less trivially, $P(x,y,z):=(x·y=z)$, as e.g. for all $y$ you have $0·y=0$.

Comment: yeah thats what i needed, `x*y = z` , when `x=z=0`. I am sorry didnt know how to translate one word from my native language. @NikolajK one more question I can't say that `y = 0` because of the quantifier?

Comment: Why $y=0$? It works for any $y$. Btw. you can easily form many other formulas. For example $x+y=z$, since if you choose any $x$, then for all $y$, there exists a $z$ so that $x+y=z$. Namely $z:=x+y$.

Comment: I think that "executable" means *satisfiable*, i.e. find an *domain* $D$ on which "assign" values to the variables and an interpretation for the *predicate* $P$ such that the formula is satisfied (i.e. "true") in it ...

Comment: As Mauro said, you probably mean *"satisfiable"*...

Comment: If so, you can try with the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and as $P$ the (ternary) relation : $x+y=z$. Then : $∃x∀y∃zP(x,y,z)$ means : $∃x∀y∃z(x+y=z)$ that is satisfied with $x := 0$ and $z := y$, because $0+n=n$, for all $n$.

Comment: In alternative, we can try with $\mathbb Z$ (the *integers*) and consider : $n+m=0$. Clearly $\forall y \exists z(y+z=0)$, and thus : $\exists x \forall y \exists z(y+z=x)$.

Comment: yeah I mean satisfiable, @MauroALLEGRANZA could you tell me are there any techniques to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: For "simple" formulae, it is more efficient to use "insight"... In general, you can use the method of [semantic tableau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) or *semantic trees* : see Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Formal-Logic-Peter-Smith/dp/0521008042/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1415025859&sr=1-1&keywords=peter+smith+logic) (2003) ... 1/2

Comment: ... or Melvin Fitting, [First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving](http://www.amazon.com/First-Order-Automated-Theorem-Proving-Computer/dp/1461275156/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415025815&sr=8-1&keywords=Melvin+Fitting+First-Order+Logic+and+Automated+Theorem+Proving) (1990). 2/2

Comment: How much technique does it take to see that, in a structure where $P(x,y,z)$ always holds, the sentence $\exists x\forall y\exists z P(x,y,z)$ will be true?? On the other hand, if by "these kinds of problems" you mean "determine whether an arbitrary first order sentence is satisfiable", there is NO technique for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a very "slim" model for the formula :

> $∃x∀y∃zP(x,y,z)$,

showing thus that it is *satisfiable*.

Consider a *domain* $D = \{ a \}$, i.e. with just one element, and assume that the *predicate* letter $P$ stands for a relation $P^D$ such that $P^D(a,a,a)$ holds.

Then, clearly, $∃x∀y∃zP(x,y,z)$ is true in $D$.

We can "mimick" this "slim" model with the natural numbers, considering $D = \{ 0 \}$ and again interpreting $P(x,y,z)$ as $x+y=z$.

We have that $0+0=0$, and thus, due to the fact that $0$ is the only element of the domain, $∃x∀y∃z(x+y=z)$ is true in $D$.